# How Can I append my array of objects in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

I get two values as name and number from input and make an object by a constructor , then I push it to an array. 
I want to append those values to my HTML file by each click from user  
and also use map to show only names. 
How can I do that? 
please help me , this is my code < br/>

```
        const name = document.getElementById("name");
        const number = document.getElementById('number');
        const container = document.getElementById("container");
        const sendBtn = document.getElementById("send-btn");

        const contacts = [];

        function ContactMaker (name, number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }
        
        sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const newContact = new ContactMaker(name.value, number.value);
            contacts.push(newContact);
            name.value ='';
            number.value = '';
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map through the contacts and add them to the DOM:

```js
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const number = document.getElementById('number');
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const sendBtn = document.getElementById("send-btn");

const contacts = [];

function ContactMaker(name, number) {
  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
}

const addToDOM = () => {
  const contactList = contacts.map(({
    name
  }) => `<li>${name}</li>`).join('');
  container.innerHTML = `<ul>${contactList}</ul>`;
}

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newContact = new ContactMaker(name.value, number.value);
  contacts.push(newContact);
  name.value = '';
  number.value = '';
  addToDOM();
})
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" />
<input id="number" type="text" />
<button id="send-btn">Send</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```